# expected identifier or '(' - xCode

Tags: xcode

I am a student who is learning and working on an App for my school. I have just started and am doing okay. However, I am recieveing the error "Expected identifier or '(' ". I have spent a few days now reading posts and googleing, and no solution I have found is working for me.

I am trying to make a Round Rect Button on the second tab of my application to link to the school's website.

Here is the .h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController  {

}


- (IBAction)Website:(id)sender;



 @end
```

and here is my .m with error commented:

```
#import "SecondViewController.h"

@interface SecondViewController ()

@end

@implementation SecondViewController 

-(IBAction)Website {
[[UIApplication sharedApplication ] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]];

}


{      **// Error is on this line[23]**
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


- (IBAction)Website;


- (IBAction)Website:(id)sender; {
}
@end
```

How can I fix this little guy?  Thank you very much!
Also, the .h file was formed by xCode, by simply control dragging from button, to .h and creating an action. Could this be the cause?

Comment: you do not have viewDidload method !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have accidentally deleted this line:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
```

above this line

```
{      **// Error is on this line[23]**
```

but for simplicity you could delete this:

```
{      **// Error is on this line[23]**
     [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
 }
```

as you are not using viewDidLoad for anything

Comment: Adding back in '- (void)viewDidLoad' worked! It pulled up an error of a duplicate, but simply deleting ' - (IBAction)Website; ' fixed that.    Thank you so much! I do not now when or how it got deleted. I left the other part of the code there, as I wasn't sure if I would ever need it later on.      Again, thank you.

Comment: If you wouldn't mind helping again.      My App is now able to run in the Simulator, but my button won't do anything for me. It this disabled in simulator? Or do I have an incorrect code?

Comment: You need to 'wire up' your button and your IBAction method in the Xib or Storyboard (open the .m file in the assistant editor so you can see it next to the Xib/Storyboard, then you can CTRL-drag a link from the button onto the method). If you get stuck then you should open a new question here to get a more detailed answer.

Comment: Got IT!   -- Agian, I greatly apprciate your help!