# How many situations can cause the error "Expected identifier or '('" in Objective-C？

Tags: objective-c

I am a new learner and I'm confusing that there is no error in every file but happen in main.m with before the function "main"

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

Comment: May it help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14282958/expected-identifier-or-xcode

Answer (score 0):

> How many situations can cause the error “Expected identifier or '('” in Objective-C？

A *lot*.

This usually indicates you have made a *syntax* error, that is you have missed typed something. Some examples:

- you have missed a closing `)` or `}`
- missed a `;` or typed a `,` instead of a `;`
- missed a closing `"`
- etc., etc.

The error message should provide a location to start your *search* – due to the nature of programming language syntax and compilers and simple typing error may not be spotted until quite some point *after* its actual location, so you start at the report line and work backwards. The automatic syntax coloring provided my Xcode (and most code editors these days) will help locate the issue; and using proper indentation at all times helps visually as well.

You must also work back through any files you have `#include` or `#import`, though you should be able to skip system ones – if there error is reported in a system include then it is usually in your code *before* that file was included.

If you are looking at a lot of code a *binary search* can help: if your comments are mainly line comments, `// ...`, then you can use block comments, `/* ... */` to temporarily surround a chunk of your code to see if the error goes away, if it does its in the commented out section, if it doesn't it is the uncommented section. If you start by commenting out roughly half the code to determine which half the error is in, then comment out half of that chunk, etc. you can quickly narrow done the location.

Keep an eye on the syntax coloring as you type and always indent code as you type and you'll soon master spotting *syntax* errors. *Semantic*, that is the *meaning* or *logic* of what you type can be more of a challenge; and it is errors in these areas which bring people to Stack Overflow – *syntax* errors you are usually expected to figure out yourself, except maybe really gnarly ones!

HTH